# How to round a float string inside a format specifier print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, format

I'm using a format specifier inside a print statement in python to print the output as columns. I have a float variable which I would like to round off to two decimal palaces without using the round function within the print statement. How can I go about doing this?

```
price = 1.25 * 3.55 #4.4375
print('{:<15}{:<15}{:<15.2f}'.format('Panadol','2 Units', price)) 
# I need the output to be 
# Panadal    2 units    4.44
```

The above piece of code throws an error stating that this is an invalid format specifier. How to achieve the above output?

Edit : Pasting the error message

```
***Run error***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__tester__.python3", line 33, in <module>
    print('{:>15}{:>15}{:>15}{:>15.2f}'.format(apple_item_name,apples_weight,apple_price_pink_lady,str(total_price_of_apples)))
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

Comment: Are you by any chance inadvertently running this with a Python 2 interpreter? This works just fine for me on Python 3.10.2

Comment: It is a python 3 compiler , don't know why it's acting up

Comment: Can you please paste the full stacktrace of the error in your question?

Comment: Add this to your code and tell us what it reports `import sys; print(sys.version_info)`

Comment: @flakes it says the following and error message added sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Comment: You used `str(total_price_of_apples)` for the input to `{:>15.2f}` remove the call to `str`

Comment: `{:<15.2f}` expects a float and it gets implicitly converted into a string. You can't perform string operations on a float. You just need to remove the call to `str`